# Button text bold on click

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a quiz game and I want the text on the button to be bold when clicked. This code works:

```
button7.Font = new Font(button7.Font.Name, button7.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
```

The problem I'm having is when I click on the 'Next' button to go to the next question, the text is still bold even though the answer hasn't been clicked. How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you can just set the button's font back when click on the "Next"?

Comment: @duDE I never thought of it like that. Thank you. I have another slightly related problem though; edited my question

Comment: That is the same logic - you change the background with button7.Background = Color.Yellow; and set it back on "Next"! BTW have a look at the answer of Austin Salonen: he got you a perfectly example!

Comment: @duDE The problem I'm having is that the red/green background color on the buttons is working for the first question but then doesn't work at all for the rest. On the btnNext_Click, I have button4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; but I have that for all four buttons.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have: assumed you have 3 buttons like "Answer A" / "Answer B" / "Next question", all three have SystemColor as a background. User clicked "Answer A" and that is correct - you set the background to Green. When user clicks on "Next" you set ALL buttons back to SystemColor - ready! :)

Comment: @duDe It's like the first question comes up, there's four buttons, I click on the correct answer, it goes green and the wrong answers go red but then when I click Next and go to the next question, it no longer does it.

Comment: In that case post your code please especially what you do on click on the "Next"!

Comment: @duDE Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315282/change-back-color-of-buttons-based-on-correct-incorrect-answer

Answer (score 2):

Just do this on "Next" button click

```
button7.Font = new Font(button7.Font.Name, button7.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: I never thought of it like that. Thank you. I have another slightly related problem though; edited my question

Comment: Your edited question part is not similar to your main question, it should be posted as different question. Your main question is about how to regain the button font while the newer one has some good amount of logic to build. If you get the answer of your main question you can choose one of the answers and can put the another question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, makes sense to do it that way. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct whichever one helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to un-bold everything when you click Next.  The code below should help (it also includes a possibly cleaner bolding implementation).

```
// usage
foreach(var button in GetAnswerButtons())
{
    button.Click += OnClickToBold;
    button.Click += OnClickSetPropertyBasedOnCorrectness;
}

nextButton.Click += NextClick;


// implementations    

private void OnClickToBold(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var button = sender as Button;

   if (button == null) return;

   button.Font = new Font(button.Font.Name, button.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void OnClickSetPropertyBasedOnCorrectness(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var button = sender as Button;

   if (button == null) return;

   button.WhateverProperty = IsCorrectAnswer(button) 
       ? valueWhenCorrect
       : valueWhenWrong;
}

private void NextClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var button in GetAnswerButtons())
    {
        button.Font = new Font(button.Font.Name, button.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        UnsetPropertyBasedOnCorrectness(button);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Button> GetAnswerButtons() { ... }
private void UnsetPropertyBasedOnCorrectness(Button b) { ... }
```