# Change back color of buttons based on correct/incorrect answer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble figuring out something.

I want the background color of the buttons to change based on whether the button clicked is the right answer or the wrong answer i.e. if the clicked button is the right answer, the background color changes to YellowGreen and if it is the wrong answer, the background color of all the wrong answers chages to red red and the right answer has a background color of YellowGreen so that the user is able to see if they got the question right or if they got it wrong, and which answer is the correct one.

It's like the first question comes up, there's four buttons, I click on the correct answer, it goes green and the wrong answers go red but then when I click Next and go to the next question, it no longer changes colors. The colors also don't change for some reason if I click one of the incorrect answers, only if I click the correct one first.

The four buttons are named button4, button5, button6 and button7. Example code I have (Have this for all four buttons):

```
if (qCorrect == 1)
{
    button4.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
    button5.BackColor = Color.Red;
    button6.BackColor = Color.Red;
    button7.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

On the btnNext_Click I have:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // swap panels
        dPanel.Visible = false;
        qPanel.Visible = true;

        button4.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        button5.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        button6.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        button7.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

        button4.Font = new Font(button4.Font.Name, button4.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        button5.Font = new Font(button5.Font.Name, button5.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        button6.Font = new Font(button6.Font.Name, button6.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        button7.Font = new Font(button7.Font.Name, button7.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular);

        if ( qCounter != qSection )
        {
            PickQuestion();
            label5.Text = "Question " + qCounter.ToString() + " of " + qSection.ToString();

            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = true;
            button7.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnNext.Enabled = false;
            label5.Text = "You answered " + qCorrect.ToString() + " questions correctly out of a possible " + qSection.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any help with the problem would be much much appreciated.

Comment: What is in your event-handler for the Next-button? Are you assigning the buttons new?

Comment: @bash.d Updated the question.

Comment: Did you reset `qCorrect`? What happens in `PickQuestion`? There must be something odd in your first assignment of the event-handlers for the Buttons...

Comment: @bash.d I could upload the program somewhere for you to take a look? The program is quite large and I can't pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: We can give it a shot... Maybe I'll find something

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it! In your event-handlers for your answer-buttons, you are always incrementing qCorrect, but you only check for `qCorrect == 1`. If you have clicked the first answer, `qCorrect` will be 1 and when you answer the second time, `qCorrect` will be 2, but you check for `qCorrect == 1`. And so on...

When you set breakpoints in the button4_click and button6_click for easy-mode, you will see what I mean! Hope this helps you further.

Comment: What do you mean by breakpoints? I've never used/seen breakpoints before.

Comment: Uhh... If you click next to the line-number in the VS2012 IDE a red dot appears, signaling a breakpoint. If you start your program using `F5` you start it in debug-mode and the program will hold, when the execution reaches the breakpoint.

Comment: Hmm so I have to make it check for qCorrect but not always qCorrect = 1 as it won't always be 1

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, it's quite erratic

Comment: I got it to light up green if the right answers is clicked and the other three go red but I can't figure out how to do it so that if the answer the user clicks is wrong, the three wrong answers go red and it highlights the correct answer in green (The button the user clicks gets a bright border around it to notify that is the selected answer). Any help?